# ddrescue recover LUKS1 partition - specific blocks

Tags: ddrescue, testdisk

I need your help!
I wanted to take hash from partition table in order to crack the old password/passphrase which somehow changed for LUKS1 partition.

I wrongly used dd command. I forgot that backups exist for a reason, of course.

I created empty txt file emptyFileHash.img and I overwrote the beginning of partition table with empty data by WRONG COMMAND ORDER

### WRONG COMMAND

`dd if=emptyFileHash.img of=/dev/sda1 bs=512 count=4097`

instead of

`dd if=/dev/sda1 of=emptyFileHash.img bs=512 count=4097`

### RESULTS FROM my memory (might be inaccurate)

0+  records in

0+  records out

2097664 bytes (2.1 MB, 2.0 MiB) copied, 0.0674719 s, 31.1 MB/s

### QUESTION - ddrescue

How to use **ddrescue** recovery option on that partition with specific blocks which I overwrote?

What is the way to read back only this chunk of data in order to recover partition and not entire 500GB disk?

### DETAILS

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ***NA***

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 976773119 976771072 465.8G unknown
```

### CURRENT HEX DATA

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=512 count=10 |hexdump -C


10+0 records in

10+0 records out

5120 bytes (5.1 kB, 5.0 KiB) copied, 0.000738207 s, 6.9 MB/s

00000000  0a 0a 4b 53 ba be 00 01  61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00  |..KS....aes.....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  78 74 73 2d 70 6c 61 69  |........xts-plai|
00000030  6e 36 34 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |n64.............|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00  |........sha256..|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 10 00 00 00 00 40  |...............@|
00000070  d4 83 26 cc ff b5 fd b2  84 7d 5d f9 d9 4d 14 32  |..&......}]..M.2|
00000080  df 47 0d c3 e5 48 3b 76  01 85 29 45 ca d9 85 fe  |.G...H;v..)E....|
00000090  bc 51 d6 7c e0 5d c3 5d  2b 94 db fb b5 20 3b 0a  |.Q.|.].]+.... ;.|
000000a0  39 e1 07 73 00 00 de 9b  61 38 66 63 35 31 64 33  |9..s....a8fc51d3|
000000b0  2d 33 63 37 64 2d 34 34  64 38 2d 61 38 30 65 2d  |-3c7d-44d8-a80e-|
000000c0  61 38 33 63 64 31 61 35  37 62 62 33 00 00 00 00  |a83cd1a57bb3....|
000000d0  00 ac 71 f3 00 0d 17 e0  5f d6 d2 31 f1 5d e6 0b  |..q....._..1.]..|
000000e0  4b 96 27 07 51 25 96 b1  94 62 61 aa d2 85 6e 99  |K.'.Q%...ba...n.|
000000f0  c6 d0 06 7c 54 8f 74 6f  00 00 00 08 00 00 0f a0  |...|T.to........|
00000100  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 02 00 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000130  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 03 f8 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000160  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 05 f0 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000190  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 07 e8 00 00 0f a0  |................|
000001c0  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 09 e0 00 00 0f a0  |................|
000001f0  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 0b d8 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000220  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000230  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000240  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 0d d0 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000250  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00001000  6e 58 3d bd 51 ab da e1  0e b4 5f e2 7d 6d 5e 9e  |nX=.Q....._.}m^.|
00001010  03 53 37 e6 57 00 a8 34  5d 89 fb 6a 8e d4 2f 9f  |.S7.W..4]..j../.|
00001020  66 73 61 99 c3 23 5f 02  c9 e0 f1 ab 31 44 83 a4  |fsa..#_.....1D..|
00001030  cf a0 3d 5a c8 80 8f 27  d9 cd 4d 1e 8e 99 7b 8c  |..=Z...'..M...{.|
00001040  fc d7 75 c1 1d 91 18 5f  ef ac 29 8b a1 a1 99 08  |..u...._..).....|
00001050  d8 d1 df 17 11 71 a6 24  71 43 e7 29 6d f0 da 36  |.....q.$qC.)m..6|
00001060  fb 02 c7 c9 67 46 b9 28  50 62 1c 93 81 2a 2d 68  |....gF.(Pb...*-h|
```

Comment: I see that only 4c 55 was overwritten which is missing letter L in LUKS partition. Correct reading from another partition 00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 01  61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00  |LUKS....aes.....| How to write back Hex using dd or using ddrescue for this chunk of data only?

Comment: with some luck, similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706071/30851 (change `0a 0a 4b 53` ..KS to `4c 55 4b 53` LUKS and hope)

Comment: Closing issue. Resolution: edit overwritten blocks manually in hexedit. LUKS1 partition recovered to the original state.