# Corrupted LUKS Header, Restoring Header does not work

Tags: linux, xfs

Sorry for my English.
A few days ago, during a routine work, I suddenly lost access to the encrypted xfs partition.  I did a reboot of the computer that got stuck.
After the reboot, the partition was no longer available.
I tried to fix it with qparted, but it seems to make things worse.  Now system sees xfs partition but empty.  I can't decode it.  There is no header copy.

Comment: anything in `hexdump -C`? unless you find the header, its game over. With LUKS 2, superficially damaged headers can sometimes be fixed, see also [this answer on cryptsetup repair](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706071/30851)

Comment: linux_tobinfrost:~ # sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda3 |grep LUKS

fdc55170  82 c6 4c 55 4b 53 37 ea  2e 9f 1d 74 04 8d 09 24  |..LUKS7....t...$|
1170a1270  0d 49 e8 38 4c 55 4b 53  1b 4b 43 09 fe 5b 55 95  |.I.8LUKS.KC..[U.|
13e9254e0  4c 55 4b 53 e4 6c 4e 84  0f f6 01 84 5d b0 1e 61  |LUKS.lN.....]..a|

found many other. after few hours - about 16 strings.

but when I:
linux_tobinfrost:~ # cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop1 luksrecover
Device /dev/loop19 is not a valid LUKS device.

Comment: cryptsetup luksDump luksheaderdamage.img
Device luksheaderdamage.img is not a valid LUKS device.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Want to recover my corrupted partition.